# Is the sentence grammatically correct and natural? If not, how could I correct it?

Tags: grammaticality, writing

> Education is not all about illuminating the truth, imparting knowledge and answering questions, but requires encouraging students' curiosity and imagination, boosts creativity and  critical thinking, as well as fosters a sound character and taste in beauty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The part of speech should be kept constant

The sentence starts with an "-ing", and so we should use the same part of speech, the gerundive, for the others.

#### Minor improvements

- No need to say "students", as it spoils the rhythm of the sentence.
- "And" is simpler than "as well as".
- The "all" in "not all about" is not ideal. You are trying to emphasise that there are other aspects that are important, so it is better to use one of these:

  - not only about
  - not solely about
  - not just about

#### How about this?

> Education is not just about illuminating the truth, imparting knowledge and answering questions, but requires encouraging curiosity and imagination, boosting creativity and critical thinking, and fostering a sound character and taste in beauty.

#### Personally, I would split it into two sentences

I had left it as one, as your question implied you wanted. But I would write it like this:

> Education is not just about illuminating the truth, imparting knowledge and answering questions. It also requires encouraging curiosity and imagination, boosting creativity and critical thinking, and fostering a sound character and taste in beauty.

Or this, which gives better parallelism between the first and second sentences. This would be important if you are intending to read this paragraph out loud.

> Education is not just about illuminating the truth, imparting knowledge and answering questions. It is also about encouraging curiosity and imagination, boosting creativity and critical thinking, and fostering a sound character and taste in beauty.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do mark as correct if you consider it so. 8-)